# Page dim with rgba on open menu not dim text color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dim the page when open the side navigation menu. When I open it, I apply rgba background color, however that does not apply to text color, even if I set a higher z-index. Also doesn't apply to input fields, but for that i set the input background to none and that works. But what I really wanted is to dim the page when I open the menu, without having to mess with the input colors and dim the text.

This is my code:

html

```
            <input style="background:none"
                id="input_01"
                class="datepicker"
                name="date"
                type="text"

                value=""
                data-valuee="">

           <div class="letter" style="background-image:url(titlebkg.jpg); vertical-align:middle; text-align:        center; color:white; font-size:3em; z-index:-1">title</div>
```

jquery

```
$( '.toggle' ).on( 'touchstart click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $body = $( 'body' ),
      $page = $( '#page' ),
      $menu = $( '#menu' ),


  $body.addClass( 'animating' );


  if ( $body.hasClass( 'menu-visible' ) ) {
   $body.addClass( 'left' );
   $('#pageContainer').css({'background-color':'none'});
  } else {
   $body.addClass( 'right' );
   $('#pageContainer').css({'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a absolute container over your content.

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="diming-container">
  </div>
  <!-- Your content -->
</div>
```

Now add the following css

```
.main-container{
   position: releative;
 }

 .diming-container{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
 }
```

If you still not getting the desired effect, try changing entire contents' (the inputs') `z-index to -1` on toggle.

Comment: can your share a JS fiddle for this or some more code so that the issue can be recreated.